# Keep div in position after user scrolls page

Tags: css, html, scroll, positioning

```
#div1 {
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 6px;
    color:#333; 
    font:normal 10px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
}
```

This div maintains a position 20x20 px from the bottom right corner of the page. But my site contains an "endless page" pagination feature and when scroll bars appear on the browser window because the content increases, the div does not maintain its position in the bottom right hand corner but rather moves up the page. How can I get this div to stay in the bottom right corner even when the user scrolls or when scroll bars appear? Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
position: fixed;
```

This should do it

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with a corner div call-out. On a horizontal scroll, the call-out stayed put while everything else moved. Making sure the container div had the following property:

```
position: relative;
```

helped in my case, along with similar code to yours.